# What is the difference between an assay and an extemporaneous preparation?

Tags: terminology, drugs

What is the difference between an assay and an extemporaneous preparation?

Can an extemporaneous preparation be labelled as the BP mixture?

Comment: Usually most extemporaneous preparations are mixtures, solutions, creams, emulsions etc. and formulations are available in the British Pharmacopoeia and others

Answer (score 2):

> An assay is an investigative (analytic) procedure for **qualitatively
>   assessing or quantitatively measuring the presence, amount, or
>   functional activity of a target entity (the analyte).**

E.g percentage purity of a given substance, viscosity, bulk density, total organic content etc.

The analyte can be a drug, a biochemical substance, or a cell in an organism or organic sample.

Extemporaneous preparation refers to the **preparation (mixing, assembling, packaging and labelling) of a medicinal product by a pharmacist (or licensed practitioner) according to prescription requirements for a specific patient** . Extemporaneous preparations  are made in  **relatively small quantities  for short-term supply and use.**

For example: Magesium trisilicate mixture can be extemporaneously prepared from the following:

- Magnesium trisilicate
- Light magnesium carbonate
- Sodium Carbonate
- Concentrated Peppermint emulsion
- Double Strength Chloroform water

*(Magnesium trisilicate mixture is an oral suspension containing 5% w/v of these excepients in suitable vehicle.)*

Guidelines of extemporaneous preparations can be found in the Pharmacopoeia.

Where you want to determine the content of say one of the excepients , is **assaying**. For example you may wish to experimentally find the actual content of magnesium in the mixture, you may perform titration with a suitable standard solution, then you can actually be able to calculate its percentage weight in volume